# creating custom ranks for a variable, groupby a another variable in Python

Tags: python, group-by, rank

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID         Category     Purchase
10001         1          7823
10001         2          7932
10002         1          10899
10003         1          79812
10003         2          80980
.....
```

There are many other IDs, who have a purchase amount for different categories. I want to rank each User in each category based on the purchase amount into say 10 groups(I may want to experiment with 5 or 20 ranks as well). So closest observations get same ranks. The pandas rank() function assigns the ranks= range of values in the category. But I want to limit number of ranks to 10. It will be equivalent of proc rank in SAS.